# How to change the location access description for an Ionic 2 iOS App? I'm using cordova geolocation plugin for my app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, geolocation

I tried changing in the AppName-Info.plist to the description I want but after the build it gets automatically replaced by the default one over below.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>$NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>$NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</string>
```

I also tried removing the cordova geolocation plugin and reinstalling as

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="Allow location access for maps"
```

but still it doesn't change the description. What I still get on my app is $NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription as my description.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to this post but I came across it while searching for an answer to the same problem. I ended up adding the following code to my ionic project config.xml file and after building and testing I can confirm that this worked.

```
<config-file parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>This app requires access to your location when the screen is on and the app is displayed to Lorem Ipsum. Your code here.</string>
    </config-file>
```

I also attached a picture showing where that bit of code went in terms of the rest of the file.

[Location Permission Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luj2h.png)

Comment: it is a savior. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not working for me. App does not prompt for location permissions. Is there any other code i should add? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I hope you have found an answer but if not here is what I did. Once you have the added the above line to your config, you then have to request permission from the user. I use the diagnostic plugin and request location authorization on page load with this line: `this.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization().then((res:any)=> {
            console.log('res in location ', res);
        })`

Comment: This tip still valid for Ionic3 :) If you're not sure which keys to use in order to override a default message, look for it in your app's `*-Info.plist` file.